# Are Cookies encrypted in REST API call over SSL (HTTPS)?

Tags: java, ssl, http-headers, session-cookies, resttemplate

I know it's a duplicate question but not very much clear from other answers.
I am using RestTemplate to call external REST APIs. The calls are over HTTPs.
Client needs to call Authentication REST API with username and password passed as body parameter and this API returns SessionId as part of Set-Cookie header. Now, In subsequent request client needs to set Session Cookie.
So, I pass Sessions Cookie as part of header.
Now my questions are:

1. Are cookies secure in https call during transmission?
2. Do I need to store certificate in JRE trust store if I do not get any error during SSL handshake? (Assuming Root CA certificate is already present in JRE trust store)
3. How can I monitor traffic to actually check if request is encrypted?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Unrelated, but is using cookies in REST APIs a common thing? EDIT: see [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/141019/should-cookies-be-used-in-a-restful-api).

Comment: AFAIK, Session Cookie (JSESSIONID) is passed as part of header in response and requests.